# Using `echo "<details>` is not working in Ubuntu Firefox

Tags: php

```
<html><body>
<details><summary id=mySummary>
        plist</summary> 
        info </br>:
        grp </p></details>
<?php
echo "<details><summary id=mySummary>
        plist</summary> 
        info </br>:
        grp </p></details>";
?>
</body></html>
```

Using `echo "<details>` is not working in Ubuntu Firefox I dont understand why? is there any solution for this?

Comment: PHP is not working in firefox at all. It just renders a piece of HTML to show in a browser. Also, please edit the question and describe what doesn't work. What does it do and what did you expect?

Comment: where did you try to execute this code?

Comment: Works fine here. Maybe you don't understand what PHP is? Trying to explain PHP will be beyond the scope of the question. I'm not trying to be a jerk.

Comment: I"d guess the file is not `.php`, or you are executing it in a way that bypasses the PHP/server.

Comment: I tried from browsers: Windows Googlechrome, Firefox, Android Browser, Iphone Safari.. working fine
but only in Ubuntu Firefox it is always opened details.. actually $plist, $info, $grp are from mysql database.. so i used php..

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with my Ubuntu 16.04 Firefox when trying to do a basic `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` output. I was met with a blank screen, and after checking the browser's `View Page Source`, the PHP code was present.

I had to install the `libapache2-mod` for PHP:

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php7.0
```

A couple of notes:

1. If your PHP version differs, then last part of that command should
   match your version.
2. Restart Apache after install and then it should work.

Comment: Actually I was uploaded to my website.. and check with all browsers, if it working fine or not..

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution now.. It is as simple as that :D

```
<html><body>
<details><summary id=mySummary>
<?php echo "$ plist"; ?></summary><p align="center">
<?php echo "$ info"; ?></br>:
<?php echo "$ grp"; ?></p></details>
</body></html>
```

It is working fine now..

Comment: ...which means that in your original echo, you were missing `$` for the variables within the string, but no space should be after the `$` if done that way.